# Where (what direcory) are the default Wordpress Widget Codes stored?

Tags: widgets

Of course we all know there are a few widgets ready by default to drag into a sidebar, but where are these stored? I'd like the copy the code of the Categories and modify it slightly to show my Theme's "Portfolio Categories" ....which are Gallery Item Categories.

I see these by default:

Calendar
Categories
Custom Menu
Links
Meta
Log in/out
Pages
Recent Comments
Recent Posts
RSS
Search
Tag Cloud
Text

Answer (score 1):

They're in the rather obviously named /wp-includes/default-widgets.php file.