# Where are widget configurations stored?

Tags: widgets

I did search and saw a similar [Where (what directory) are the default Wordpress Widget Codes stored?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23796/where-what-direcory-are-the-default-wordpress-widget-codes-stored) but this is not my question.

When I have a lot of widgets configured, say a few dozen RSS feeds each in its own widget, where exactly is this data stored? I'd like to be able to copy this data to import into another theme using the same plugin/widget without needing to retype all the urls fed into the rss widgets.

Update - it seems this request is looking to solve an issue at the wrong level. Elsewhere, I was advised to just use a plugin, [Widget Importer & Exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-importer-exporter/) and it preserved the widget settings very well. No need to mess with the source or SQL.

Comment: IMO Widgets are difficult to transfer. WordPress keeps this data in a serialized array in the options table. You can search this using `LIKE %..%` for "widget"

Comment: It sounds like I might find them in the database, and even export, but the import will not happen, a bunch of copy/paste entering into the new theme widgets. Thx for the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The widgets data is stored in `wp_options` table as serialized array, with `option_name` started by `widget_`:

[image: Widgets Data]